# NodeJS - Server access from outside/LAN IP is failed

Tags: node.js, express, lan

I made a demo app using ExpressJS.

Accessing API through POSTMAN in the system works fine. But I can not access the same with my mobile browser, where both Mobile and Server system are connected to same wifi.

**My server.js code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log("Listening on Port 3000");
});

app.get('/server/identify', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var data = {
        "meta": {
            "status": "success",
            "message": "Server is running"
        }
    };
    res.json(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to expose port 3000 on your local network and then access the machine using it's local network IP address. No one will be able to access it unless the port is open on your machine.

Take a look at something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), this should handle exposing a port for you and make it accessible to anyone you give the link as long as they're connected to the internet. This might help you build your application and test it quickly on your machine and mobile before deploying it.

Comment: Superb. You really saved my day. Ngrok is awesome.  :)

Comment: @NaveenKumarV No worries, there is a similar node based variant called localtunnel - https://localtunnel.github.io/www/ which is sometimes good for node projects as well as it has programatic hooks. I prefer ngrok though as it's useful across multiple projects and forces me not to couple my project to it.

Answer (score 1):

**The steps I followed to resolve this:** (Thanks to @Elliot Blackburn)

```
Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound rules > New Rule >

Port > Provide port number (in my case 3000) > Select "Allow the Connection" >

Select all (Domain, private and public) > Provide Name and Description > FINISH

(In command prompt)
>> node server.js
Server running in port 3000
```

***[Optional] With ngrok.exe (no need to install)***

```
(In command prompt)
>> node server.js
Server running in port 3000

>> ngrok http 3000

ngrok by @inconshreveable

Session Status                online
Version                       2.2.8
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://92a8b6b1.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000
Forwarding                    https://92a8b6b1.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend exposing port 3000 if you're using ngrok, ngrok is a bit safer to use and doesn't require you to expose any ports manually.

Comment: My nodejs app uses port 3000 by default. So to tell ngrok to use port 3000 with localhost when forwarded from random.ngrok.io with its default port 80, I needed to run 'ngrok http 3000'. Nice tool for the day. :)